# Cannot start HBase master: loaded coprocessors are: []

Tags: hbase

In my HBase installation (distributed mode master + 2 region servers) with external zookeeper running on top of Hadoop distributed installation (master node + secondary master node + two data nodes) I am not able to start HBase master. Region servers starts with no problem. HbaseMaster is failing with error message:

```
2013-09-06 13:00:13,503 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Master server abort: loaded coprocessors are: []
2013-09-06 13:00:13,503 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:157)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:183)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:189)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:602)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.startServiceThreads(HMaster.java:913)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:557)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:391)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:208)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
... 6 more
```

Comment: I tried to delete ZNode for /hbase but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. Misconfiguration in hbase-site.xml file. Wrong hostname in hbase.master.info.bindAddress